# Passing a value using onClick and updating two state values with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this onClick event in this link:

```
<a href="#" onClick={() => show()}>{data.game.title}</a>
```

This is used like this to or hide an element:

```
const [isShown, setIsShown] = React.useState(false);

const show = (title) => setIsShown(true);
```

Now I also want to pass a value from this onClick and save it in my state.

How would I pass a value to the function?

I tried doing this, and nothing happens:

```
const [gameIdVal, setGameIdValue] = React.useState(false);

<a href="#" onClick={() => show(data.game.id)}>{data.game.title}</a>

const show = (gameId) => setIsShown(true), setGameIdValue(gameId);
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Identifier 'setGameIdValue' has already been declared
```

But I don't understand this because it isn't set anywhere.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
const show = (gameId) => setIsShown(true), setGameIdValue(gameId);
```

you didn’t use curly braces and JS parser think you want to declare a function named *setGameIdValue*.
correct form :

```
const show = (gameId) => {
  setIsShown(true);
  setGameIdValue(gameId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add curly braces like this:

```
const show = (gameId) => {
  setIsShown(true);
  setGameIdValue(gameId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need more than just a single line of code in your **arrow function's** body, then you can use the `block body syntax`.

Important things to keep in mind with the `block syntax` is that it uses `curly braces {}` to wrap the function body.

You can do like this:

```
const [gameIdVal, setGameIdValue] = React.useState(false);

const show = (gameId) => {
    setIsShown(true);
    setGameIdValue(gameId)};
}
```